# What to do with atypical actions in REST?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, ember.js

Let's say that I'm creating a user. I would

```
POST http://example.com/users
```

That user record gets created an email goes out and then I want to use the same API later to do a complete registration for that user. Registration includes, marking their email validated. Creating a blank account for them and a plethora of other setup kind of things. Let's say all that could be put in one controller. Which of these would be RESTful still? Or acceptable?

```
A) REGISTER http://example.com/users/1
B) POST http://example.com/users/1?action=register
C) POST http://example.com/users/1/register
D) POST http://example.com/users/1/registrations
```

I've been doing a lot of looking into this and haven't been able to find a guiding source yet.

Comment: I'd go with C) post the token. Return 200 ok or 404 if no token 500 if error

Comment: That's my instinct too.

Comment: You can return in the header location the link to the activation link aka resource

Comment: Maybe you can request this as a topic (maybe it is already debated....don't know) http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/topics

Comment: So you're thinking the API should have a link to the registration link in an application... instead of in the API.

Comment: I would also use C and you can maybe also can do this then `http://example.com/site?controller=users&id=1&action=register` and that could work on same API too, i mean, that should be possible for good API or?

Comment: @ka_lin, thanks for pointing out the Topics secion. I did not know it existed.

Comment: No probs, happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of subjective.

A, B and C are not RESTful, D may be, it's acceptable.

Why?

A: `REGISTER` is not a HTTP method.

B: The behaviour of the endpoint depending on a query parameter. (URI not auto-descriptive)

C: You don't access to the resource but give an action

D: There you have the idea of accessing to the resource

I don't know all what is behind your project (security, database schema..), but I'd suggest something like

```
POST http://domain.com/users/1/confirmationToken
POST http://domain.com/users/1/emails/1/confirmationToken
```

Comment: Can i ask how this is redirected on the server like `a=a&b=b` or `x=a/b/c` ?

Comment: The given URL isnt a real file, so some kind of redirecting must go on or?

Comment: Usually this is handled by the router you're using. If you don't use one, then you have to check the validity of the url before any action and do the redirection by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer :)

Comment: I'd argue that your suggestion is like C since I'm making an arbitrary route with the idea that I'd pass an extra uri to identify a specific action. And I'd argue that there are only two HTTP methods, `POST` and `GET` all the others are made up for the sake of applications making A the most restful in your argument for D.

I think this is probably why I can't find anything that defines this.

Comment: As I said, I don't know anything about his project, maybe `registrations` is an attribute of user, and `D` have more sense. For the HTTP method it depends on what you base on, I work with this [definition](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). And myself I implements `PATCH` support in my apis, be cause it's needed. There are no official standards for REST, all are implementations of the [resource-oriented model](https://www.w3.org/TR/ws-arch/#resource_oriented_model)

Comment: Thanks for the your input. It's given me more to think about, for sure.